# JoinColumn on OneToMany side not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

Why I can't create `@JoinColumn` on `OneToMany` side? It throws:

```
2017-05-17 09:13:34.063  WARN 7724 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roleMapper' defined in file [C:\MyProjects\myjnia\Myjnia_Inzynier\target\classes\com\carwash\mappers\RoleMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in com.carwash.MyjniaInzynierApplication: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available

    . //always the same but with every mapper interface
    .
    .
```

When I change the direction - put `JoinColumn` at `Wash` side, it works, but I want to have an reference to `Wash` from `Admin` table.

`Admin` class:

```
 public class Admin {
        private Integer adminId;
        private User userId;
        private List<Wash> washId;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "washAdmin", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "washId")
        public List<Wash> getWashId() {
            return washId;
        }
```

`Wash` class:

```
public class Wash {
    private Integer washId;
    private String name;
    private WashLocation washLocation;
    private List<Worker> washWorker;
    private List<Reservation> washReservation;
    private List<WashWashType> washTypes;
    private Admin washAdmin;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JsonIgnore
    public Admin getWashAdmin() {
        return washAdmin;
    }

    public void setWashAdmin(Admin washAdmin) {
        this.washAdmin = washAdmin;
    }
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: @Jens updated..

Comment: `@JoinColumn` specifies the name of the column in the ELEMENT, i.e in `Wash`. That is how it is. It doesnt matter whether you put the `@JoinColumn` in `Wash` or in `Admin` ... the FK will always go in the element

Comment: If you want a FK in the `Admin` then the relation is not `@OneToMany` since there is no physical way you can model that with an FK on that side!!! Use `@OneToOne` in that case

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to make your relation bidirectional, you have two option, either you have unidirectional relation and the joinColumn will be in the  owning entity or you will have unidirectional.

check this example how to create unidirectional relation

> http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/Hibernate-Unidirectional-OneToMany-and-ManyToOne-Concepts

JoinColumn should be in the owningentity (the one which does not have the collection in your case) and the mappedby should be in the none owningentity

Comment: I have created a Unidirectional with join table but it doesn't create me a column in the `Admin` table...

Comment: not with joinTable , if you want a foreign key column inside your table you need to use ManyToOne and OneToMany in the 2 types of the relation, joinTable will create a junction table which contains the two columns having the ids of the two sides of the relation in case the relation exists

Comment: So there it is the question...look above I have created the realtion but it throws fails..